# mod_rewrite proxy URL missing images/css

Tags: proxy, url-rewriting, proxypass, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite using Proxy flag to redirect from one URL folder to another site subdomain as follow:

The .htaccess file placed inside http://www.domain.com/test/ folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^($|/.*) http://subsite.site.com/$1 [L,P]
```

The problem, images, CSS and links are not showing up properly. Links appear to be pointing back to: http:// www. domin .com/linkname.html

I've tried doing RewriteBase /test/  and /  with no luck, and couldn't figure out any other way to do it.

What am I missing in above code to make it work with relative paths at destination URL?

Comment: Are you sure that the urls in question are relative?

Comment: If I put the rewrite rules in .htaccess at the root folder, it works fine, but in a subfolder images fail.

Comment: images/css appear as  http://domain . com/thesubsitelink/  instead of being http://domain . com/test/thesubsitelink/

Comment: It seems only way to resolve this by using mod_proxy_html

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you want to change internal content?

Mod_rewrite only changes headers, not content and you would definitely need something else like mod_proxy_html. However, rewriting content just to change urls can normally be completely avoided (assuming you have control of your content) by making all paths legitimately relative. In such cases all paths in content should be like: `linkname.html` or `some_path_from_here/linkname.html` instead of `/linkname.html` or `some_path_from_here/linkname.html`

Comment: Thanks..Yes I would need change content. I have tried mod_proxy_html but that failed as well. Only way I was able to fix this by putting mod_rewrite rules in the root to proxy redirect each folder on the destination. But that would overwrite my current site.

This is my failed mod_proxy_html code, any sugg?

ProxyPass /test/ http://subdomain.DestinationSite.com/ 
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://subdomain.DestinationSite.com /test 

<Location /test/>
  ProxyPassReverse http://subdomain.DestinationSite.com/
  SetOutputFilter proxy-html
  ProxyHTMLURLMap / /test/
  ProxyHTMLURLMap /test /test
</Location>